# FirebaseMessagingService show notification only when background

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

A FCM message can have one of `data`, `notification` or both. The notification that system generates using `notification` lacks functionalities, so I removed `notification` and sent `data` only. Therefore, I have to create notifications myself.

Creating and showing notifications was easy, but I do not want to show a notification when my app (specifically MainActivity, but it has only one activity, anyway) is already on the foreground. Most apps do not show notifications when they are on the foreground.

How do I know in `onMessageReceived` if my app is not on the foreground?

```
class MessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService()
{
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?)
    {
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage?.data?.isNotEmpty() == true)
        {
            //Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.data)

            ......

            if "Only when my app is on the background or not running?"
                sendNotification("Got a message.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can implement **Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks** by which you can detect if the app is in foreground or backroudn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Method checks if the app is in background or not
 *
 * @param context Application context
 * @return True/False
 */
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```